# AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest show progressbar during image downloading?

Tags: iphone, afnetworking, uiprogressview

How to show a progressbar during image downloading?

My code here:

```
 [picView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    NSLog(@"success");


} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}    
 ];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will get answer for this question in below page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821428/afnetworking-setimagewithurlrequest-download-progress/36984041#36984041

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A progress bar is probably not the correct UI for this. Instead, you should probably use an *indeterminate* progress indicator (spinning bars). To do this in AFNetworking, use `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`, hiding the progress indicator in success and failure.

If you did want to track the progress of a request, you would have to use `AFImageRequestOperation`, and do `setDownloadProgressBlock:`.

Comment: Mattt, can you elaborate on why showing a progress bar is not the correct way to show the progress of an image download?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this cocoa pod: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLRemoteImageView . It allow you to show a progress indicator and also be updated about UIImage download progress. It uses objective-c internals and AFNetworking UIImage category to achieve what you want. I hope it helps you.