# AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest download progress

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, afnetworking, progress

I am using this code to set image to UIImageView.

```
NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageToLoad]];

    [imageView setImageWithURLRequest:URLRequest placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        [cell.image setImage:image];
        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Nothing
    }];
```

But I want to track download progress with that method, is it possbile to do it in setImageWithURLRequest method?

Normally I do this to show loading progress percentage:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Start download..."];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // success
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done."];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // failed
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Failed."];
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading... %0.0f%%", totalBytesRead*100*1.0/(totalBytesRead+totalBytesExpectedToRead)]];
    }];
```

Comment: I'd answered for this question at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744024/afnetworking-3-0-setimagewithurlrequest-download-progress/36983966#36983966](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744024/afnetworking-3-0-setimagewithurlrequest-download-progress/36983966#36983966)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, no UIImageView+AFNetworking category doesn't have this functionality.  However, it can easily be added to by adding this method to the category:

```
-(void)setDownloadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead,   long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))block{
   [self.af_imageRequestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:block];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Note: as of may 2013 it appears you *can* actually just call `setDownloadProgressBlock` - no need for the category

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this cocoa pod: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLRemoteImageView . It uses objective-c internals to achieve what you want. I hope it helps you.