# AFNetworking 3.0 setImageWithURLRequest download progress

Tags: ios, uiimageview, afnetworking, progress, afnetworking-3

Does anyone have a nice working solution for getting the download progress when using the [UIImageView+AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h) category and [AFNetworking 3.0](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide).

This [category](https://gist.github.com/martinpilch/5269512), which I did use for versions up till 3.0 has stopped working now.

Here is my own experimental [version](https://gist.github.com/knutigro/85d3463f06f660d7a67d) which sadly, for the moment, crashes randomly.

Comment: Did you check this one -> https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLRemoteImageView

Comment: please refer my answer below.
I've made a pull request to AFNetworking, unfortunately it's rejected. Till then you can use this, if you don't want to change/upgrade your AFNetworking version.

Comment: Thats a good effort @iOSEnthusiatic . By the way I also gave them a pullrequest some days ago https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/3306.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modified version of AFNetworking 3.0 in which you can show a progress while loading image from server using **UIImageView+AFNetworking** category.

**https://github.com/rushisangani/AFNetworking**

Please replace following files with original AFNetworking files.

```
UIImageView+AFNetworking.h,
UIImageView+AFNetworking.m,

UIImage+ImageDownloader.h,
UIImage+ImageDownloader.m
```

NOTE: If you update your pod then this will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at AFImageDownloader this, it is used by the UIImageView category to download images. In this class you

```
- (nullable AFImageDownloadReceipt *)downloadImageForURLRequest:  (NSURLRequest *)request
                                                    success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse  * _Nullable response, UIImage *responseObject))success
                                                    failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *error))failure;
```

It returns a receipt which has a NSURLSessionDataTask *task property. NSURLSessionDataTask has different properties of how bytes download, expected bytes to receive etc. Perhaps you can use this and achieve your task.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding few lines in **UIImageView+AFNetworking.h**

1. Place this code at top of the file under the import statement

   ```
   static void * AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext = &AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext;
   ```
2. And you need to register the observer to track the bytes received by adding below line under the function `setImageWithURLRequest` at the position

   ```
   if (cachedImage) {
       // AFNetworking default code
   }
   else{
       // AFNetworking default code
       // Our new lines to track the download
       [self.af_activeImageDownloadReceipt.task addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"state" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)0 context:AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext];
       [self.af_activeImageDownloadReceipt.task addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"countOfBytesReceived" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)0 context:AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext];
   }
   ```
3. Add this new function at end.

   ```
   #pragma mark - NSKeyValueObserving

   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                         ofObject:(id)object
                           change:(__unused NSDictionary *)change
                          context:(void *)context
   {
       if (context == AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext) {

           if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))]) {
               if ([object countOfBytesExpectedToReceive] > 0) {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       //You can do your stuff at here like show progress
                       NSLog(@"Progress : %f",[object countOfBytesReceived] / ([object countOfBytesExpectedToReceive] * 1.0f));

                   });
               }
           }

           if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(state))]) {
               if ([(NSURLSessionTask *)object state] == NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted) {
                   @try {
                       [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(state))];
                       NSLog(@"Image Download Complete");
                       if (context == AFTaskCountOfBytesReceivedContext) {
                           [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(countOfBytesReceived))];
                       }
                   }
                   @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {}
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```